# add block to Authorize.net payment template

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, module, payment, layout

in the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/cc.phtml` template, around line 76, there is a spot to echo out child html.  how do I reference that block to add a child into it?

I'm trying to add a section in my layout class, but it doesn't appear to be working correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="payment.method.authorizenet">
            <block type="abt_authnet/foo_bar_baz" name="foobar" as="foobar" template="abt/foobar.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

Am I doing this wrong?  my feeling is I'm referencing the wrong block?

Comment: What payment method are you using? Authorize.net or Saved CC?

Comment: @jharrison.au, I'm using authorize.net

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with authorize.net but when I see this correctly, the template `payment/form/cc.phtml` is from `Mage_Payment` and therefore not from Authorize.net

But both templates from Authorize.net

- `authorizenet/directpost/form.phtml`
- `authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml`

has a `<?php echo $_form->getChildHtml() ?>` somewhere in the code, where you can echo any content.

But obviosuly this is in the review step:

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">
        <block type="directpost/form" name="payment.form.directpost" template="authorizenet/directpost/form.phtml">
            <action method="setMethodInfo"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

So you can reference the form block:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_review>
        <reference name="payment.form.directpost">
            <block type="abt_authnet/foo_bar_baz" name="foobar" as="foobar" template="abt/foobar.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
</layout>
```

Where is the `payment.method.authorizenet` from? Just a guess?

Comment: seems like `payment.method.authorizenet` is from `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods` -> `getPaymentMethodFormHtml`, not really remember though. the block is created in `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container` -> `_prepareLayout`